Неожиданное завершение работы цикла асинхронной функции
Написал код с использованием асинхронной функции, но после нескольких минут он завершает свой цикл, хотя не должен.
Пишу код для вытягивания расписания всех факультетов и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Возможно ли, что ошибка в большом количестве итераций (в одном факультете примерно 4000 записей)
Вот сообщение, которое выходит:
 File "/home/sgtu_bot/microservice/main.py", line 88, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()

  File "/home/sgtu_bot/microservice/main.py", line 76, in main
    schedule = await get_schedule(group['ID'], week_number)

  File "/home/sgtu_bot/microservice/main.py", line 24, in get_schedule
    async with session.get(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 560, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 894, in start
    with self._timer:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 720, in __exit__
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None

asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

Буду признателен за помощь. Сам код:
   async with conn_pool.acquire() as conn:
        for number in numbers:
            current_number = number
        #for faculty in faculties.keys():
            for course in range(1, 7):
                groups = await get_groups(current_number, course)
                for group in groups:
                    for week_number in range(1, 49):
                        schedule = await get_schedule(group['ID'], week_number)
                        if len(schedule) != 0:
                            for dictionary in schedule:
                                async with conn.transaction():
                                    await insert_schedule(conn, dictionary, i)
                                    i += 1

    await conn_pool.close()



Вы сами то не путаетесь в таком количестве вложенных циклов? И вообще было бы здорово взглянуть на самодостаточный(минимально воспроизводимый) пример.

Смотрите стек вызовов. Тут явно аиохттп сваливается по таймауту (скорее всего сервер не отвечает на такое количество запросов ). Вам нужно поставить работу с внешкой в блоки try except и обернуть в while. Также стоит поставить какие-нибудь задержки для повторного запроса.
